# Using regex to parse html

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch data from example.com using file_get_contents and preg_match_all but not getting the desired result.

The url is example.com
data to be fetched in this url is abc="hello" - i want to fetch hello and store inside a variable so far i have

```
$url = "example.com";
$pagecontent = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('/abc="([^"]+)"/',$pagecontent ,$m); 
print_r($m);
```

The result I am getting is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )
```

When the result should be `hello`.

Comment: You used the bad title

Comment: To get an html attribute, the best way is to use the DOM, and in particular for your task, is to use/learn XPath.

Comment: but abc is not an html attribute like <a href> or <table> or <span> it is just some random text in the document... the xpath seems to be best for well form html or xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have formatted datas, use the structure of your datas, don't use a direct string approach:

```
$url = "example.com";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLfile($url);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodeList = $xp->query('//@abc');

foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you want a more costumed result, look at the XPath query language.

Comment: getting Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in example.com, line: 25 in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\crawl.php on line 21

Comment: @DragonFire: it isn't important, most of the time, html files aren't well formatted. You can prevent these warnings redirecting all html errors to the  libxml error handler. I will add the code to do it.

Comment: You can have an access to these errors using [`libxml_get_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php)

Comment: ok now getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\crawl.php on line 48 looking into it

Comment: can we chat.... i can invite you to chat room and work with the real url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139193/discussion-between-dragonfire-and-casimir-et-hippolyte).

Comment: Sorry no, I'm not a chatter, but if you want an answer that fits better your case, add in your question a more descriptive example.

Comment: alright no problem, thanks i am working on the problem now... i guest python seems a lot easier than php for this

Comment: `data-ttlurl=` doesn't exist in the file. `seller-info` exists (30 occurrences). Whatever stop to search stupid solutions with direct string approaches (regex) and take the time to learn how to use and query the DOM. Trying to do it with Python instead of PHP is the same problem and honest users will give you the same answer.

Comment: @DragonFire: Yes! You find the way to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EItANXUklc

Comment: @DragonFire: if you have problems to load the file, use [`libxml_set_streams_context`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php)

Comment: @DragonFire: If it doesn't suffice, use cUrl to know what is the exact problem.

Comment: your code is working fine if you add $url = file_get_contents($url); after the first line, now i am reading about manipulating data using how to use and query the DOM as mentioned by you

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

You get the parameter from the url.

```
$subject = $_GET['abc'];

preg_match_all("/^(([^\"]+))$/", $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: the parameter does not exist in url, it exists in page content